# NgModule, @NgModule, AppModule

Tags: angular

New to Angular2. Great product. Again, documents are hard to crack, sometimes reads like a PhD textbook, so I'm just trying to sum-it-up in **plain English**, with some questions too.

**Module**, a generic programming term we gather some related things together, for example in .NET world, a .cs file for a class, or even a project all could be seen as a module.

**NgModule** is also a Module. Now it's more Angular-specific so it's prefixed with "Ng" and called NgModule.

**@NgModule** is no longer a generic term, it's the actual code defining a **class** following specific Angular format.

Here is a typical pre-generated *src/app/app.module.ts*:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({     // looks like it's always called "@NgModule", can't be @NgModule25. My understanding is even though I want to have more than one NgModule in my project, because each is defined in its own .ts file, so compile won't complain about ambiguous names.
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],  // notice this import ending with an extra "s", still don't know why need to import again the same module after the lines above. Just tell myself to remember import twice.
  providers:    [ Logger ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],  // what this NgModule has, like inside a .csproj 
  exports:      [ AppComponent ],  // list out all components will be exposed inside this NgModule, consider this is a list of all "public" stuffs from a class.
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],  // which component(s) to start with
})
export class AppModule    // "AppModule" is a default name for root module. My guess for non-root NgModule(s), whatever you give a name here becomes the name of class outside can see, just make sure the name match exactly the file name.
{
...  // more code here for this NgModule (class), for example C#.NET anything at class level but not in functions.
}
```

`AppComponent`, I don't know if there must be a default component so like Module it's called *AppComponent*, or maybe because those modules we `import` has an entry component with the same name so we have to use it to wire them up.

About NgModule file name, if `AppModule` is `app.module`, does it have to start with `App`? what about the NgModule name is `myFirstModule25`? Any rule to follow?

Sorry for the long post. Because these terms are so tightly-related that it's easier to use one code base to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm going to be prompt with my answers, but there's a lot to sift through and I don't want to ramble forever...

**Module**: You're right, it's just a library of components or other bits of your code. It is a generic programming term.

**NgModule**: Don't think about this too much in the context you stated, it's not a module. It's a decorator you're importing to use (see next).

**@NgModule()**: Implementing the `NgModule` decorator to classify a `class` as an Angular Module.

The `AppComponent` is being declared in the `AppModule` (an Angular Module thanks to the `NgModule` decorator) as the entry point (the loaded component) by it's use in the `bootstrap` field.

Does `AppModule` need to be saved as `app.module.ts`, no. But the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) does recommend the suffix of what type of file it is... Modules have `.module.ts`, Components are `.component.ts`.

Finally, yea you can technically call your module/class `myFirstModule25`, but I wouldn't, it's not really conventional... First off classes should always start uppercase. And also, while you don't need to end the module/class with `Module` that is the convention that the Angular CLI uses, and I would say look at that convention for reference to what's normal/appropriate. (Along with the Style Guide)